# TypeError: color must be int or single-element tuple

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Here is the error encountered:

> TypeError: color must be int or single-element tuple

Here is the code I am running:

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw
from PIL import ImageFont, ImageOps

label1 = "VIKRAM"
font = ImageFont.truetype('D:/vikram/pythonProject/fonts/BalloonCraft-9YBK7.ttf', 800)
line_height = sum(font.getmetrics())
fontimage1 = Image.new('L', (font.getsize(label1)[0], line_height))
ImageDraw.Draw(fontimage1).text((0,0),str(label1),stroke_width=10, stroke_fill=(0, 0, 0), fill=255, font=font)
fontimage1 = fontimage1.rotate(90, resample=Image.NEAREST, expand=True)
orig = Image.open('F:/desktop/Kitty/PSI Hello Kitty Theme Personalized Door Poster-1.png')
orig.paste((135, 255, 135), box=(2200, 1500), mask=fontimage1)
orig.show()
```

The error occurs in `ImageDraw.Draw` for the `stroke_fill` parameter.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Which line does the error occur on?

Comment: Line No: 8 , I Cannot give Stroke_Fill color ..

Comment: Try to just provide `stroke_fill='black'`, does this solve the problem?

Comment: No its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I belive as you put the 'L' in `Image.new` your image will be gray scale, therefore you can't specify a RGB tuple for `stroke_fill` because you only have black shades. As specified in the error message you have to use an int or a single tuple.

Answer (score 0):

I have a better way to deal with this error
any time when you have `color` or `stroke_fill` param, always use strings like 'red', 'green', 'black'

for above code, have it this way

```
ImageDraw.Draw(fontimage1).text((0,0),str(label1),stroke_width=10, stroke_fill='black', fill=255, font=font)
```